# how to use ajax to put value from javascript variable into a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to get the value of a javascript variable and put it into a mysql database. I am trying to use jquery ajax function in (test.html) to Post the variable to a separate PHP file (external.php). I'm not sure why it's not working, I would appreciate any insight. Here are my two files:

Here is test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
      var longitude = "print a longitude";


      $.ajax({
          url: "external.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: { "longitude": longitude }
      });
});



    </script>




  </body>
</html>
```

And here is external.php:

```
 <?php

    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
    echo json_encode($longitude);
    ?>
```

Comment: **What** isn't working? It seems like you don't have a callback in your ajax-function, add that and console.log the data

Comment: add a callback to ajax call `success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
          }`

Comment: How do you even know it's not working? You aren't doing anything with the response and have no error handler for the ajax

Comment: I entered the callback you gave and the console does indeed print the value of the variable. So the issue must be with how it is being sent to the php.

Comment: Any ideas as to why the php says that it $longitude is an undefined index?

Comment: How can there be any issue if what you send is properly returned?

Comment: in the php file, nothing is echoing and it is saying that the variable is an undefined index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works perfectly fine for me:

The external.php file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
    echo json_encode($longitude);
?>
```

The test.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      var longitude = "print a longitude";


      $.ajax({
          url: "external.php",
          method: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { "longitude": longitude },
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
      });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure you are not running your file as:

```
file:///C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/XAMPP/htdocs/test.html
```

If you run it like this you would get this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: file:///C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/XAMPP/htdocs/external.php
Line Number 5, Column 3:
```

What you need to do is run Apache and then run the file as:

```
http://localhost/test.html
```

Below is the screenshot of what I get:

[image]